# Обьясните как работает код

Tags: python

Мне непонятно как работает данный код

```
str = "one"
number = 0
pp = "__{0}__{1:08X}__"

for i in range(0, 10):
    print(pp.format(str, number))
    number = i
```

Вывод следующий

```
__one__00000000__
__one__00000000__
__one__00000001__
__one__00000002__
__one__00000003__
__one__00000004__
__one__00000005__
__one__00000006__
__one__00000007__
__one__00000008__
```

Мне непонятно что за `"__{0}__{1:08X}__"` что там вообще происходит?

Comment: https://pythonru.com/osnovy/formatirovanie-v-python-s-pomoshhju-format

Answer (score -1):

Подробное объяснение кода:

```
str = "one" # к переменной `str` присваивается строка 'one' 
number = 0 # к переменной `number` присваивается число 0
pp = "__{0}__{1:08X}__" # шаблон записи строки

for i in range(0, 10): # в данном цикле итерируемся 10 раз
    print(pp.format(str, number)) # выводим строку, к которой применяем шаблон `pp`, где скобку словаря '{0}' меняем на значение строки `str`, а '{1:08X}' форматирует к виду '0000000'+значение `i`. 


    number = i # присваивает к `number` значение `i`, где `i` с каждым циклом увеличивается на 1 от 0 до 10 невключительно.
```

Также можете подробнее ознакомиться с форматированием строки, как подсказали в комментариях к вопросу, [здесь](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/formatirovanie-v-python-s-pomoshhju-format)